# Both Windows + L and Windows + R keys are not working

Tags: release-freya, keyboard-shortcuts

For some reason both my super keys aren't working. I tried going to `system settings->keyboard->options` but I don't see any options in `Alt/Win key behavior` that says `Super` in it. Just `Meta` and `Hyper`. Not sure what those keys even mean.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how can you say keys are not working?...what you have tried